# How can I create new window with same state as parent window?

Tags: javascript

Can i open new tab in javascript in the same state as the parent tab? If yes how can I do it?

I have used window.open() but it just opens the new tab with a new blank state.

Comment: What do you mean by "same state"?

Comment: It means whenever I open new tab all the js variable and object of parent element will be loaded to the child element.

Comment: 1) In a tabbed browser, such as Chrome, each tab contains its own window object. There isn't a parent/child relationship between tabs. 2) What higher-level goal do you have in mind?

Comment: Then can I pass object to new tab when it is created?
I want to create a multi user application that uses two different windows which communicate with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot exactly create window with the same state. The way you're explaining it, it sounds like you'd like to `fork` the parent window like a unix process.

What might be helpful in your case would be to use the `postMessage` method on the window to send message objects between windows.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Sample from mdn:

```
/*
 * In window A's scripts, with A being on <http://example.com:8080>:
 */

var popup = window.open(...popup details...);

// When the popup has fully loaded, if not blocked by a popup blocker:

// This does nothing, assuming the window hasn't changed its location.
popup.postMessage("The user is 'bob' and the password is 'secret'",
                  "https://secure.example.net");

// This will successfully queue a message to be sent to the popup, assuming
// the window hasn't changed its location.
popup.postMessage("hello there!", "http://example.org");

function receiveMessage(event)
{
  // Do we trust the sender of this message?  (might be
  // different from what we originally opened, for example).
  if (event.origin !== "http://example.org")
    return;

  // event.source is popup
  // event.data is "hi there yourself!  the secret response is: rheeeeet!"
}
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
```

This is a quite simple pattern but from there, you should be able to send more complex messages.